# $variable after <br> is not showing in echo in php

Tags: php, echo

I'm learning basics in php, and I was trying to add multiple arguments in **echo** command. But the variable after `<br>` is not showing.

```
$number1=10;
echo "number 1 is: ".$number1."<br>";
$number2=20;
echo "number 2 is: ".$number2;
echo "<br> ".$number1+$number2;
```

and the output should be:

```
number 1 is: 10
number 2 is: 20
30
```

But the output is:

```
number 1 is: 10
number 2 is: 2020
```

So what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the braces to the sum operation.

```
$number1=10;
echo "number 1 is: ".$number1."<br>";
$number2=20;
echo "number 2 is: ".$number2;
echo "<br> ".($number1+$number2);
```

The output will be:

```
number 1 is: 10
number 2 is: 20
30
```

Answer (score 2):

used this code

```
$number1=10;
echo "number 1 is: ".$number1."<br>";
$number2=20;
echo "number 2 is: ".$number2;
$total= $number1+$number2;
echo "<br> ".$total;

?>
```

The output will be:

```
number 1 is: 10
number 2 is: 20
30
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers just state a solution, this answer explains whats happening and how to prevent the unexpected behavior in 2 ways.

The dot operator has the same precedence as + and -.

Considering

```
$number1 = 10;
$number2 = 20;
echo "<br> ".$number1+$number2;
```

The dot you've used is a **string** operator, not a numeric operator.
What's happening:

1. `"<br>"` and `10` are concatenated with the dot operator to `"<br>10"`.
2. `"<br>10"` is added to $number2 (`20`) with the numeric + operator.
3. Non-empty, non-numeric strings are converted to 0. Meaning `"<br>10" = 0`.
4. `0+20` results in 20 which makes line 3: `echo 20;`

This can be solved by changing the precedences by using brackets `echo "<br> ". ($number1 + $number2);` or the less seen option, by passing more arguments to the `echo` language construct: `echo "<br> ", $number1 + $number2;` (Note the **comma** instead of a dot). Each argument will be evaluated first before outputting them all together.

Personally I use the second option (multiple arguments) in cases like this.

Comment: Isn't `$number1` = 10, though?

Comment: @Chipster Yep... Got a little confused myself. I've changed it. Thx.

Comment: Great answer. I wish I could +1 again, but I'm already doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You should revise code within bracket

```
echo "<br> ". ($number1 + $number2);
```

to get the result you want.

Reason: each operation has precendence level

Get reference: http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/InfixPrefixandPostfixExpressions.html